# Installing Siremis stuck on Database Configuration

Tags: sip-server, kamailio

I have install Kamailio 4.3.4 on Ubuntu 16.0.5 LTS. I want to install Siremis 4.3.0 but stuck on Wizard step 2 (Database Configuration) there is message "Something went wrong". I found error 500 action=update on console inspect element. I have try installing Siremis 5.1.0 and still not working stuck on step 2.

My Apache ver 2.4.10, My Php ver 7.0.33, Mysql 14.14

Please any advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like one of the dependencies is not met:

**Check your permissions are set:**

```
make prepare24
make chown
```

**Check Mod Rewrite is enabled:**

```
a2enmod rewrite
service apache2 reload
```

**Check PHP Mod is Enabled in Apache**

On 16.04 installing PHP doesn't automatically add the PHP Apache mod, should be a package like libapache2-mod-php, you can verify that Apache is actually parsing PHP files by [setting up a PhpInfo page.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php)

**Remove the Lock File & Try Again**
When you run the installer a lockfile is created to prevent running the installer multiple times.

Once we empty the database with:

```
mysql> drop database siremis;
```

We can remove the lockfile and try again (from the Siremis directory):

```
rm install.lock
```

[I did a writeup on installing Siremis on Ubuntu 18.04 which works fine.](https://nickvsnetworking.com/kamailio-bytes-siremis-installation/)

Comment: thanks for your help dude, it works. I think my fault is missing some php mod